# Laravel 5.4 casts not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4

My Model

```
class Subscriber extends Model
{
    protected $casts = [
        'filters' => 'object'
    ];
}
```

In tinker:

```
$s = App\Subscriber::first();
$s->filters
// prints serialized json:
// ""{\"maxHyra\":\"8000\",\"minAntalRum\":\"2\",\"Ungdom\":\"true\",\"Student\":\"true\",\"Korttid\":\"true\",\"Bostadssnabben\":\"true\",\"_token\":\"0Y2f3eAl27ikrujvw7VBWNOaNXxchygaFUDSo4s4\"}""

json_decode($s->filters)
// prints a neat php object.
```

So obviously my data in the attribute is fine, and json_decode works. But the cast is not working. I have also tried accessors without success.

Comment: The piece of code that you posted look's fine. Or you're hiding/omitting some relevant code, or that's a Laravel bug. If it's the second option, create an issue on Laravel github (http://github.com/laravel/framework)

Comment: Thanks, I tried to isolate it, at the moment that is my controller code. Will do soon If I have no other ideas. Im assuming I have some mistake somewhere else in project for now :/

Comment: Try to replicate the issue in a blank Laravel project with a minimal code, so you can confirm if it's your mistake or not.

Comment: Does object casting work with JSON?  I don't see that documented anywhere, the only thing I see in the docs or have ever tried is array casting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`$casts` works both ways, inserting and retriveving. There's no need to use `json_encode` to convert a array to string by yourself first. Laravel will do when it is in the `$casts` array.

for example:

Model Sample:

```
protected $casts = ['ext' => 'object'];
```

SampleController:

```
App\Sample::create([
'ext'=>['hello'=>'world']
])
```

Answer (score 3):

Casts works both ways, that is both for insert and retrieving! I had kept json_encode when inserting new Models.